# Help with skyrim combination

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm stuck at the combination lock in the caves for the quest that you get the golden claw... I know the right combination, but the pillars are actually stuck! none of the will turn, and they are all stuck on the chicken head thing! PLEASE HELP!! :(

Comment: Didnt I see this question asked last night already? (though now you are atleast telling us which of the puzzles)

Comment: I guess the other question is gone.. And it wont let me remove my down vote for some reason.. Anywho, if you click on them and they do not rotate, your game is likely bugged, not sure what can be done.

Comment: garrett, please accept my apologies for deleting your question yesterday. For some reason I scanned it as an answer in your feed and thus deleted it for not being an answer.

Comment: Yesterday his question did not provide any information to what quest he was on or the location of the pillars.  As there are many pillar puzzles, we asked for more information and did not receive any.  It most-likely got closed as a un-answerable question.

Comment: Yea I've asked this already, but it got deleted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a cave puzzle glitched somewhere else. It had something to do with spikes. Try leaving the cave and entering again. It seems Skyrim caves run on Windows OS.

Comment: oops... I tried to vote this comment up but it says I can't and voted it down automatically. Thanks though!

Comment: @garret Don't worry it wasn't you. You need like 125 points to vote down questions. Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

[Watch this Video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzKx1txxiYM)  If the pillars shown in this tutorial do not rotate, your game is bugged.  It would be best to revert to an older save.

Spoiler, that Video shows you how to solve the problem.